# C++ calls Python in Anaconda3 error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, anaconda, zlib

I need to use the C++ code to call the Python code(which used TensorFlow), Python was installed by Anaconda3. But I found my code couldn't load the python code because the tensorflow module was not loaded successfully. The clear question is below.

My C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <python.h>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import tensorflow");
    Py_Finalize();
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

The output:

```
2021-08-03 00:23:24.264014: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import data
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data import experimental
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.readers import CsvDataset
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\ops\readers.py", line 23, in <module>
    import gzip
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\gzip.py", line 9, in <module>
    import zlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'
Hello World!
```

I used `base` conda env, it has `zlib` module, and I tested it in Python was OK:

```
(base) PS C:\windows\system32> python
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
2021-08-03 00:26:11.966844: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
>>>
```

Here is my machine configuration:

```
OS: Windows 10
IDE: VS 2019
Conda version: 4.10.3
Python version: 3.8.8
VS project configuration: 
    Additional Include Directories: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\include
    Additional Library Directories: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\libs
    Additional Dependencies: python38.lib
```

**UPDATE: Environment variables**

```
PYTHONHOME=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
PYTHONPATH is not set.
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin\;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;...
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <python.h>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import os");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(os.environ['PYTHONHOME']) ");
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.path)");
    //PyRun_SimpleString("import tensorflow");
    Py_Finalize();
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

here is the output:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
['C:\\Users\\dqs\\source\\repos\\test\\x64\\Release\\python38.zip', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\dqs\\source\\repos\\test\\x64\\Release', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\locket-0.2.1-py3.8.egg', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

Comment: try to add PYTHONHOME in your windows system Evironment  variables to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\ and check your PYTHONPATH

Comment: @Adib I had set it, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Adib I'm sorry, I only set the PYTHONHOME but not set PYTHONPATH, is it ok?

Comment: @Adib I add `PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.path)");`, I attach the output at the question's end.

Comment: @Adib Ok... I just updated the question, my program read PYTHONHOME successfully...

Comment: What about `PyRun_SimpleString("import zlib");`? In theory it should work *OOTB*, as it's built-in.

Comment: @CristiFati It returned `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'`

Comment: I assume that in the *Python* console, it works.

Comment: @CristiFati Yes! In Python, everything is alright. The error only occurs in C++ calling Python.

Comment: @S DQ I replicated your config and setting and Im running code without any error

Comment: Please also add the commands used to build the code.

Comment: @CristiFati Full build commands: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RwkQzBg73z/

Comment: @CristiFati Oh! I got it! I just deleted the C://tool/vcpkg then it was run! It means that my program calls the wrong zlib directory...

Comment: Congratulations! :) `Searching C:\tool\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib\zlib.lib:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid confusion and as the reported error message is different to what usually in conflict between imported library and linked library is reported.
I'm adding this answer to this particular question,**(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib')**

In this case dll library that is used to build executable and libraries that path environment variable is referring are different.
to avoid this conflict remove any  python dlls, headers and import libraries from the vcpkg install.

```
vcpkg remove <pkg>
```

here **pkg** is referring to python version that is installed in vcpkg.